# How to text-align a label in css

Tags: html, css

I want to apply some css styling on my labels for my web page but have no idea how to make it work. At first, I thought I could type
`label{text-align: center}` but it's not giving my any styling at all. What should I type to style my labels? This is my code:

```html
<label for="fname"><b>First Name</b></label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" id="fname" required>
```

Thanks in advance everyone!
[image]

Comment: Please edit your code (now a snippet) to include more than one row of items. With only one line, there is nothing to "center" to.

Comment: @AhmedMourad I've updated the answer check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, `text-align:center` didn't work because basically the `label` elements are `inline`

inline elements are elements who their `display` is set to `inline` , explicitly or by default

these elements won't accept any `width` or `height` and only get ENOUGH `width` and `height` for their content
they even don't accept vertical margins...

so your label here is as small as it's content and there is no room to change your text's alignment...
you can change it's display to make it's text centered

Here You can see what I said, I've added another label and changed it's display and colored the labels so you can see diffrence

```html
<style>
     label{
         background: khaki;
     }
    .lname{
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
     }
     .test{
         display: block;
     }
</style>
<label class="fname" for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" id="fname" >
<label class="lname" for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Last Name" name="lname" id="lname" required>
<label class="test" for="test">Test</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Test" name="test" id="test" required>
```

[image: three different states you might want]

I think what you want is the middle one

========%%%%=======%%%%=========

Ok Based On Your comment and image
it's not label who you want to center, it's your input

```html
<style>
     input{
        display:block;
        text-align:center;
         width: 100%;
     }
     input::placeholder{
         text-align: center;
     }
</style>
<label class="fname" for="fname">First Name</label>
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter First Name" name="fname" id="fname" >
```

Comment: But when I run you snippet, I get the same style as my webpage. To clarify it once again, the small header over the input (First name) is at the left side. I basically want to move it to the right of the page

Comment: So you want label to be centered, run the first snippet, inside of it i demonstrated three different states,, you can choose between them, i think the middle one is what you want where the label is centered and input is left aligned